# How do I match a Regular Expression in a Happy parser?

Tags: javascript, parsing, haskell, parser-generator, happy

I'm writing a JavaScript parser with [Happy](http://www.haskell.org/happy/) and I need to match a regular expression.  I don't want to fully parse the regex, just store it as a string.

The relevant part of my AST looks like this:

```
data PrimaryExpr
    -- | Literal integer
    = ExpLitInt     Integer
    -- | Literal strings
    | ExpLitStr     String
    -- | Identifier
    | ExpId         String
    -- | Bracketed expression
    | ExpBrackExp   Expression
    -- | This (current object)
    | ExpThis
    -- | Regular Expression
    | ExpRegex      String
    -- | Arrays
    | ExpArray      ArrayLit
    -- | Objects
    | ExpObject     [(PropName, Assignment)]
    deriving Show
```

This is the relevant Happy code:

```
primaryExpr :: { PrimaryExpr }
    : LITINT          { ExpLitInt $1 }
    | LITSTR          { ExpLitStr $1 }
    | ID              { ExpId $1 }
    | THIS            { ExpThis }
    | regex           { ExpRegex $1 }
    | arrayLit        { ExpArray $1 }
    | objectLit       { ExpObject $1 }
    | '(' expression ')' { ExpBrackExp $2 }
```

My question is, how should I define my `regex` non-terminal?  Is this kind of structure right?

```
regex :: { String }
    : '/' whatHere? '/' { $2 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define regex as a terminal that is recognized by the lexer (i.e. LITREGEX).

```
primaryExpr :: { PrimaryExpr }
    : LITINT          { ExpLitInt $1 }
    | LITSTR          { ExpLitStr $1 }
    | LITREGEX        { ExpRegex $1 }
    | ID              { ExpId $1 }
    | THIS            { ExpThis }
    | arrayLit        { ExpArray $1 }
    | objectLit       { ExpObject $1 }
    | '(' expression ')' { ExpBrackExp $2 }
```

Comment: Ok, good idea.  That leads on to the next question - how do I get an Alex lexer to match a regular expression? (I could ask this as a separate question if you think that's a better idea?)

Comment: I'm no Alex expert, but something like `\/[^\/]*\/ { \s -> LITREGEX . init . tail $ s }`.  This doesn't allow for escaped `/`'s in the regex.  YMMV

Comment: To do this properly, you'll need to deal with backslash-escaped `/`'s, and `/`'s inside character classes.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I'm coming up with.  It's perfect other than that though.  It matches simple regexes, just not ones with escaped forward slashes.  I'll work on it, thank you!

Comment: Final solution: `\/([^\/]|\\\/)*\/[gim]*  { \s -> Regex s }`

Comment: This still allows the regex to terminate if there's an unescaped forward slash inside a character class...

Comment: You can use a start code to change the rules when you're inside a regex, and another start code to change the rules again when you're inside a character class inside a regex.

Comment: How does that work? Would this work? `\/([^\/]|\\\/|\[[^\]]*\/)*\/[gim]* { \s -> Regex s }`

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the comment, need a bit more room.

Something like (spaced out and commented):

```
/             forward slash
(  \\.        either: an escaped character
|  [^\[/\\]           anything which isn't / or [ or \
|  \[                 a character class containing:
     [^\]]*              anything which isn't ] any number of times
   \]                   
)*            any number of times
/             forward slash
```

Condensed:

```
/(\\.|[^\[/\\]|\[[^\]]*\])*/
```

Comment: This is great, cheers.  I think it's nicer than mine anyway.  I had to escape the forward slashes and add modifiers so here is the end product: `\/(\\.|[^\[\/]|\[[^\]]*\])*\/[gim]* { \s -> Regex s }`

Comment: I was going to say I wasn't sure what you'd need to escape for Happy but you seem to have figured it out :)

Comment: Character classes allow the first character to be a ] without it closing the class

Comment: @pat: sometimes. Not in Javascript. I got bitten by this recently :) Here it is in Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/UFtKt.png

Comment: @pat: PCRE and PCRE-compatible stuff allows it. They also allow `[^]]` :)

Comment: @Porges This was working great for me, but I've come up against some cases where it matches too much.  If the input is `a.replace(/\\/g, '/');`, it matches `/\\/g, '/` rather than stopping after the g.  Can you shed any light on why it's doing this?

Comment: @NickBrunt: I can't replicate that in my test (which isn't Happy, admittedly)... it will match that much if you forget to escape the "a.replace(/\\/g, '/');" correctly. Is this being read in from a file or are you typing it in as a test?

Comment: For example, if that's going into a string in Haskell it would look like `"a.replace(/\\\\/g, '/');"`

Comment: @Porges First of all, thank you very much for replying at all on an old question! It's being read in from a file so the escapes will be put in automatically.  It's actually part of a very large JavaScript library but I factored it down to this piece of code that is giving me the problem.  I now have that on its own in a file and I get the same error.  It matches the regex as `/\\/g, '/`.  Another example is this: `a = 0.5 / 2; // Comment` where it matches the regex as `/ 2; /`.  I'm baffled as to why it's doing it.  I can put my program in pastebin or something for you if you want?

Comment: @Porges I've put a zip file on my server with my lexer in it.  Feel free to have a look if you want.  I'll probably take this down once I solve the problem, sorry future people. http://nickbrunt.com/uni/Lexer.zip

Comment: @NickBrunt: I see where the first problem is. The first character class in my regex is `[^\[/\\]`, but when you've copied/escaped it, it is `[^\[\/]`. This should be `[^\[\/\\]`. The second problem is a bit harder... the ECMAScript spec http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf defines some grammars for RegExp, but then *never uses them*! There's some more discussion on this on the Mozilla mailing list: http://old.nabble.com/Exactly-where-is-a-RegularExpressionLiteral-allowed--to22666418.html#a22666418 To handle this correctly, you're going to smarten the lexer.

Comment: @NickBrunt: If you look at the edit history, I actually changed my answer only 3 minutes before you posted that comment... so you must have picked it up before I did that. Sorry, I should have checked the example code you posted.

Comment: @Porges Ah yes, of course, my bad.  I did look over your answer again but clearly not closely enough!  I have solved the second problem as well with a pretty nasty hack, but at least it works now.  The problem cropped up a few times and I noticed that it's always when there is a comment at the end of the line.  It always matches the first `/` of the comment and the last `/` of the regex, so I added `[^\/]` at the end of my regex so that it makes sure that the next character is not a `/`, thus eliminating the possibility of matching the first `/`.  I am now obviously matching one too many chars

Comment: so I had to add this to my lexer function to right that wrong: `Regex s -> Left (Regex (init s), (last s):xs)` where the tuple is the token followed by the rest of the code.  This hack promptly brought up another bug.  It now won't match regexes followed by a newline, so I changed the regex AGAIN to this which is the current working (fingers crossed) version: `\/(\\.|[^\[\/\\]|\[[^\]]*\])*\/[gim]*([^\/]|[\n\r]) { \s -> Regex s }`. Phew, well it works for now. Thanks so much for your help! P.S. I've added a bounty of 100 reputation which I'm going to give to you for your help.